# One error bar on each plot is in weird spot in Rggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

I have a error bar which is in the wrong place on each plot, i have checked the raw data and nothing unusual is there, i have also tried changing the y limits but that doesnt change anything. Anyone have a clue how to make these error bars normal. I have my code below

```
#Nutrients 
Nutrient_soil <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\ezxct5\\OneDrive - The University of Nottingham\\Project Data\\Data\\Experiment summary data sets\\Kale , char alkaline soil\\Soil Nutrient R ready.csv")
str(Nutrient_soil)
Nutrient_soil$Char.Type <-as.factor(Nutrient_soil$Char.Type)
Nutrient_soil$Application.rate....<-as.factor(Nutrient_soil$Application.rate....)
Nutrient_soil$Particle.size <- as.factor(Nutrient_soil$Particle.size)

#P
Pbar<-ggplot(Nutrient_soil,)+
geom_bar(aes(x=Treatment, y=P),stat="identity")+
theme_classic()+
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, size=8, color="black"))+
geom_errorbar(aes(x=Treatment,ymin=P-p.s.e, ymax=P+p.s.e),width=0.3, position=position_dodge(0.9))+
ylab("P (mg/kg)")




#K
Kbar <- ggplot(Nutrient_soil)+
geom_bar(aes(x=Treatment, y=K),stat="identity")+
theme_classic()+
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, size=8, color="black"))+
geom_errorbar(aes(x=Treatment,ymin=K-k.s.e, ymax=K+k.s.e),width=0.3, position=position_dodge(0.9))+
ylab("K (mg/kg)")


#Ca
Cabar<-ggplot(Nutrient_soil)+
geom_bar(aes(x=Treatment, y=Ca),stat="identity")+
theme_classic()+
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, size=8, color="black"))+
geom_errorbar(aes(x=Treatment,ymin=Ca-ca.s.e, ymax=Ca+ca.s.e),width=0.3, position=position_dodge(0.9))+
ylab("Ca (mg/kg)")
#Mg
Mgbar <- ggplot(Nutrient_soil)+
geom_bar(aes(x=Treatment, y=Mg),stat="identity")+
theme_classic()+
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, size=8, color="black"))+
geom_errorbar(aes(x=Treatment,ymin=Mg-mg.s.e, ymax=Mg+mg.s.e),width=0.3, position=position_dodge(0.9))+
ylab("Mg (mg/kg)")

plot_grid(Pbar, Kbar, Cabar, Mgbar, labels=c("a","b","c","d"), label_size=12)
```

[Graph result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4boqJ.png)

Comment: Does `any(duplicated(Nutrient_soil$Treatment))` return `TRUE`? If so, you might want to double check where the duplication comes from. The default for `geom_bar()` stacks duplicated observations, whereas `geom_errorbar()` does not.

Comment: Yes it returns true. Not sure how to look where that duplication is coming from though.

Comment: Figured it out two had the same label.